# Not able to get Datatable return type in to object

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datatable

i have created method for getting data from database. This method has DataTable as return type. When trying to call this method it is throwing me an exception of object reference is not set an instance of an object. Here is the method and how i am using it.

```
 public DataTable executeSelect (String _query, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
    {
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable = null;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            myCommand.Connection = openConnection();
            myCommand.CommandText = _query;
            myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myadapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
            myadapter.Fill(ds);
            dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.Write( e.StackTrace.ToString());

            return null;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Below code showing how above method is being used to result into a datatable

```
            string sp_name = "sLot";
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[]{
                 new SqlParameter("@stype","ML"),
                new SqlParameter("@ttype","B"),
                new SqlParameter("@code",comp_code)

            };               

            DataTable data = dbc.executeSelect(sp_name, param);
```

Note: This uses Stored Procedure name "sLot"

Comment: last line is throwing error i.e DataTable data = dbc.executeSelect(sp_name, param);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are getting an excdeption, therefore you return null instead of a `DataTable`. You have to set `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure` if you use one.

```
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Of course there are other possible reasons for a `NullReferenceException`, but you haven't provided enough informations. If the last line throws the exception as commented `dbc` is null. You can  make `executeSelect` static or create an instance of the type where the method is declared.

Comment: Its throwing error before entering the executeSelect method i.e here DataTable data = dbc.executeSelect(sp_name, param);

Comment: You were right i forget to declare dbc with new keyword as i was in impression that its a static method. Thanks Tim .